# confusing grep pattern with BRE

Tags: linux, shell, grep

greptest.txt:

```
cat sheep
dog money
money cat
ca+
caa
```

Since `+` is not included in BRE(POSIX Basic Regular Expression),  command `grep 'ca+' greptest.txt` treats it as a plain text character, and the selected line is as expected:

```
ca+
```

however if I add `\` in front of `+`, then the pattern `ca\+` acts like extended regular expression, and the selected lines are as followings:

```
cat sheep
money cat
ca+
caa
```

but, why `ca\+` acts like extended regular expression without grep command option `-E`?

Comment: [The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_02) so implementations can do whatever they wish.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `grep 'ca\+'`. The standard does **not** define how `\+` should be interpreted in basic regular expressions. Maybe this was done to allow implementations to add extensions or maybe (as is often the case) the standard authors had to find the a common feature set between many existing implementations.

> https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html
>
> The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped
>  ( '\' ) is undefined, except for:
>
> ```
> The characters ')', '(', '{', and '}'
>
> The digits 1 to 9 inclusive (see BREs Matching Multiple Characters)
>
> A character inside a bracket expression
> ```

The manual page for [gnu grep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) documents the syntax extension your expression is using (if you are using gnu grep).

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>
> ```
>    In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (,
>    and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed
>    versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
> ```